# Javascript error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null

Tags: php, javascript

```
function offer() {
inlineAlert("", "Обработка торгового предложения - пожалуйста, подождите...");
$("#confirmModal").modal("hide");
var csv = "";
var sum = 0;
$("#right .slot").each(function(i, e) {
    csv += $(this).data("id") + ",";
    sum += $(this).data("price");
});
var turl = $("#tradeurl").val();
var remember = $("#remember").is(":checked") ? "on" : "off";
var url = "/withdraw_js";
if (DEPOSIT) {
    url = "/deposit_js";
}
$.ajax({
    "url": url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        "assetids": csv,
        "tradeurl": turl,
        "checksum": sum,
        "remember": remember
    },

    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
```

в data передает null. Помогите понять почему.
withdraw_js:

```
    case 'withdraw_js':
    if(!$user) exit(json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'error'=>'Вам необходимо авторизоватся на сайте чтобы продолжить.')));
    $items = array();
    $assetids = explode(',', $_GET['assetids']);
    $sum = 0;
    $prices = file_get_contents('prices.txt');
    $prices = json_decode($prices, true);
    $norm_itms = '';
    foreach ($assetids as $key) {
        if($key == "") continue;
        $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `id` = '.$db->quote($key));
        $row = $sql->fetch();
        $items[$row['botid']] = $row['market_hash_name'];
        $sum += $prices['response']['items'][$row['market_hash_name']]['value']*10;
        $norm_itms = $norm_itms.$row['market_hash_name'].',';
    }
    $out = array('success'=>false,'error'=>'');
    if(count($items) > 1) {
        $out = array('success'=>false,'error'=>'You choose more bots');
    } elseif($user['balance'] < $sum) {
        $out = array('success'=>false,'error'=>'Вам нужно больше монет!');
    } else {
        reset($items);
        $bot = key($items);
        $s = $db->query('SELECT `name` FROM `bots` WHERE `id` = '.$db->quote($bot));
        $r = $s->fetch();
        $db->exec('UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = `balance` - '.$sum.' WHERE `steamid` = '.$user['steamid']);
        $partner = extract_partner($_GET['tradeurl']);
        $token = extract_token($_GET['tradeurl']);
        $out = curl('http://'.$ip.':'.(3000+$bot).'/sendTradeMe/?names='.urlencode($norm_itms).'&partner='.$partner.'&token='.$token.'&checksum='.$_GET['checksum'].'&steamid='.$user['steamid']);
        $out = json_decode($out, true);
        if($out['success'] == false) {
            $db->exec('UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = `balance` + '.$sum.' WHERE `steamid` = '.$user['steamid']);
        } else {
            foreach ($assetids as $key) {
                $db->exec('DELETE FROM `items` WHERE `id` = '.$db->quote($key));
            }
            $out['bot'] = $r['name'];
            $db->exec('INSERT INTO `trades` SET `id` = '.$db->quote($out['tid']).', `bot_id` = '.$db->quote($bot).', `code` = '.$db->quote($out['code']).', `status` = 2, `user` = '.$db->quote($user['steamid']).', `summa` = '.'-'.$db->quote($_GET['checksum']).', `time` = '.$db->quote(time()));
        }
    }
    exit(json_encode($out));
    break;
```

Comment: Нажать в браузере F12, перейти на закладку Network и посмотреть, что сервер браузеру отдает

Comment: @oleg kalenchuk 'Objectbalance: "2000"error: "none"items: Array[8]success: true__proto__: Object
2offers.js?v=106:341' '2 null'

Comment: Гляньте еще хедеры (я такое видел когда-то когда Content-Type не тот был)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно разобраться попадают ли данные из вашего скрипта в `"/withdraw_js"` или `"/deposit_js"` и что это файлы передают в ответ на запрос. 
Здесь `"url"` должно быть без кавычек

```
$.ajax({
    "url": url,
    type: "GET",
```

Рекомендую также добавить в скрипт обработку ошибок

```
success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
},    
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Без кавычек? Так - url : url ?

Comment: Да. Смотрели что в консоли отображает функция error:?

Comment: Ничего. Либо я не знаю где смотреть. Chrome -> F12 -> console

Comment: url : url - не помогло